# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder tracking data isn't returning to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, automationstudio

We configured Marketing Cloud Connect v5 to sync data between Salesforce and Marketing Cloud. Everything works fine. I can send individual emails in Sales Cloud, using Marketing Cloud Email templates. In other way I can use Syncronized Data Extention in Marketing Cloud to send emails in Marketing Cloud to Contacts of Salesforce (Sales Cloud). 
Now I need to **filter some Salesforce data** and use these filtered data in a **new Journey**. The first thing that I thought was create a filtered Report in Salesforce and use it as a Data Source on MC Journey Builder... but I discovered that Salesforce Report isn't available as Journey Builder Data Source.
So I created a new Data Extension (DE - I created as a *normal Data Extention because Salesforce Data Extention isn't available as Entry Source of Journey Builder*) with 3 properties: Id(text), name (text) and email (emailaddress). Its important to say that I'm saving Salesforce 18 char ID on **Id Property** and mark ID field as **Subscriber Key**. 
After that I created an automation (using Automation Studio) to extract some filtered data from Syncronized Data Extention (of Salesforce Contact), save it in my new DE.
And at the end I created a new Journey (With this new DE as source) to send emails with some business and marketing logics. To send email I checked that Option to "**Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud**".
When I run the Automation and that "call" the journey almost everything works fine... the emails were sent and all steps of journey were concluded, but **tracking information wasn't sent back to Salesforce**...

I read in some forums and here on StackExchange that if I use Salesforce ID as Subscriber Key, the Connect App would sent my tracking information back to Salesforce... But it's not happend. Anybody know what am I doing wrong? Or any other solution to my scenario?
Thank you everyone and any ideas I will appreciate!

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that I didn't link my custom Data Extension with Contact on Contact Builder.

**Solution:**

I entered on Contact Builder, created a new Attribute Group. After that I clicked on "Link Data Extensions".

[image: Link Data Extensions]

So I select my Data Extension (DE) and linked my Primary Key of my DE (Salesforce Contact ID) with Marketing Cloud Contact Key.

[image: Linking DE with MC Contact]

At the end I clicked on Save and executed my Journey with my DE as Entry Source. After about 1 hour I received tracking data records on Salesforce.

[image: Salesforce contact related list]