# Journey Builder sends not displayed in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

i try to track Journey sends in Sales Cloud under IER. I'am using  the SFMC Connector.

1. In SFMC i use the 18 digit **ID** as subscriber key.
2. Journey data Extension is located in "Data Extension folder"
3. Jounrey data Extension relates Subscriberky on **ID**
4. The Send tracking to sales Cloud is TRUE on email activities in Journey.
5. The Data Extension is in a attribute group and is connected to the Contact in. 18 digit **ID** to Contact_Key.

But still no Individual Email Results are displayed in on the Contact Object in Sales Cloud. :/

Any thoughts or ideas what could be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons:

- First, consider there is a minimum of appx. 1 hour lag between any activity and report back to SF. This can be longer - check your settings under the Marketing Cloud tab in the CRM
- Are you using Scope by User? If so, consider looking at permissions.

Finally, I suggest you test a Journey based on a **Salesforce Event Entry** to see and narrow down - you'd be able to tell if the problem is the way you set up the Connector/User/Configuration or the specific DE !
For the specific DE - try this solution:
[Marketing Cloud Journey Builder tracking data isn't returning to Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219303/marketing-cloud-journey-builder-tracking-data-isnt-returning-to-salesforce?rq=1)

Also,

Try this article to troubleshoot:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_troubleshoot_email_sends_and_tracking.htm&type=5